# How do I add a 'Create symlink' to the right mouse button drag and drop context menu in windows?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, drag-and-drop

Specifically I want to add a command to create a symlink of the selected file/folder and place it in the destination folder.

Answer (score 6):

[Shell Link Extension.](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html)

The menu you refer to is called the *Drag and Drop* menu.  Programs that want to add themselves to that menu create a Drag and Drop *handler*.

Answer (score 1):

surfasb's comment is out of date. The new link is:

https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html

Comment: Can confirm. This link is ever so slightly newer.